# New branches not appearing on Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I have a repository on Bitbucket under Mercurial. As Bitbucket not supporting Mercurial (or almost not supporting) I change Mercurial to Git by reimporting repository.

Now when I create a release branch using git-flow everything looks fine locally. I push that new branch and it isn't shown on Bitbucket. I push with all checkboxes checked (using SourceTree // SS is taken when release branch is closed) 
[image]
but nothing changed on Bitbucket. All commits from the release branch are shown like from develop branch.

Is it something with my configuration or something else?

---

```
$ git ls-remote origin
```

not returning my created release branch.

Comment: Did you git fetch?

Comment: @matt, yes, I tried to fetch also

Comment: Do a fetch-and-prune. Now `git branch --all`. Do you see origin/release?

Comment: @matt I saw release branches except new one. And something like this https://prnt.sc/sx9ydn is it fine?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. — Okay, so if your release branch is not listed, then you are right, it was never pushed to bitbucket. But it isn't listed locally either, so it isn't clear to me how you know this was ever a real branch. Did you actually _do_ anything on this branch? And how did you push it, and what happened when you did?

Comment: @matt I just now tried to create new feature branch. It was created. I added new commit. I run command `branch -a` and branch isn't visible. I didn't make push.

Comment: What command did you use to create the new branch?

Comment: @matt `git flow feature start test111 develop`

Comment: Ah, well, okay, now you're out of my league. It sounds like what's failing is whatever `get flow` is supposed to do. I know nothing of that. What if you just make the branch in the normal old-fashioned git way, without `git flow`?

Comment: I mean for example you're using Sourcetree. It knows how to make a branch. How about making the branch with Sourcetree? Can you push it then?

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is set to track origin, try the command `$git branch -a`